# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showModal' of null

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm attempting to take the following code [here](https://github.com/auth0-blog/redux-auth/blob/master/components/Navbar.js) and refactor the login into a modal.  Unfortunately when clicking `Login` I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showModal' of null
```

Here is my Navigation.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Button, Modal, Nav, Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { IndexLinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import Login from '../Login/Login';
import Logout from '../Logout/Logout';
import { loginUser, logoutUser } from '../../actions/actions'
import './Navigation.css'

export default class Navigation extends Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = {
            showModal: false
        };
    }

    open() {
        this.showModal.setState = true
    }

    close() {
        this.showModal.setState = false
        }

    render() {

        const { dispatch, isAuthenticated, errorMessage } = this.props;


        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar className="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                    <Navbar.Header>
                        <Navbar.Brand>
                            <IndexLinkContainer to="/"><a href="/">myApp</a></IndexLinkContainer>
                        </Navbar.Brand>
                        <Navbar.Toggle />
                    </Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Collapse>
                        <Nav pullRight>

                            {!isAuthenticated &&
                            <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.open}>Login</Button>
                            }

                            {isAuthenticated &&
                            <Logout onLogoutClick={() => dispatch(logoutUser())} />
                            }

                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>

                <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>Login</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <Login
                            errorMessage={errorMessage}
                            onLoginClick={ creds => dispatch(loginUser(creds)) }
                        />
                    </Modal.Body>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

Navigation.propTypes = {
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    errorMessage: PropTypes.string,
}
```

The page loads fine but my modal isn't launching from clicking the button.  I'm using react and react-bootstrap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right so you have several bugs in your code:

When using an ES6 class as you are doing here, your methods do not autobind meaning that if you have an event handler on your JSX like `this.open`, then `this` is the wrong context therefore anything you do in the function will not be able to use `this`. To fix, bind somewhere, preferably in the constructor but can be done inline:

```
onClick={this.open.bind(this)}
```

Second issue is that the function itself is doing something kind of random. Of course `this.showModal` throws an error because of the binding issue mentioned above, but even with the binding, that is not how you access/set state variables. Instead, switch to:

```
this.setState({ showModal: true }) // or false for `close`
```

It should then start working properly.

Comment: I'm extremely new here so I'm attempting to parse your answer by trying to get it to fit in my existing code.  Humour a rookie here on how it would actually look?  I tried putting in the `onClick={this.open.bind(this)}` after my `this.state...` in the constructor and I get an error on the `.` after `this`

Comment: think I got it with the following.  In the constructor I added - `this.open = this.open.bind(this)` then I have the following before render - `open() {this.setState ({showModal: true})}` the modal comes up :)

Comment: Haha for sure, learning React and JavaScript can be daunting :) So forget what I said about the constructor to make your life easier. I meant add it on your actual JSX: `<Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.open.bind(this)}>Login</Button>`

Comment: Yeah that's it! Way to go!

Comment: ah!  ok thnx for the follow up so it seems it can be done a few different ways?  I'll test your method too!

Comment: Yeah it's more explicit in the constructor but just as correct. You should also look at the proposed autobinding ES7 feature (double colon) which would allow you to bind like this: `::this.open`